# Java DefaultExecutor fails on long path on Windows 7 error=267

Tags: java, windows

Environment:

- Windows 7
- HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled=1 (Type: REG_DWORD)

The command below **runs perfectly** on Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\dev\Documents\projects\projectx_solution\java\projectx\build\bin\squeezer -R 1 C:\Users\dev\Documents\work\w1\SPOH_ANO12_PDC2.fast -L \\?\c:\Users\dev\Documents\jira\work\ABC04214017-long-path-qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm2\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm3\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm-qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm4\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm5\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcv\qwertypoiuyalskdjfhg\ABC04214017_03.raw_fhhzcqaj_wLM(4)\objs\RemPartic.fast -H 100000
```

**However**, when I attempt to run the same command via Java's DefaultExecutor

```
 executor.execute(cmdLine);
```

then I get the following **IOException**:

"Cannot run program .... Create Process error=267, the directory name is invalid".

This is somehow related to Windows long path limitation. Does anyone know a solution / workaround? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this using plain old java:

```
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] cmd = { "C:\\Users\\dev\\Documents\\projects\\projectx_solution\\java\\projectx\\build\\bin\\squeezer",
            "-R",
            "1",
            "C:\\Users\\dev\\Documents\\work\\w1\\SPOH_ANO12_PDC2.fast",
            "-L",
            "c:\\Users\\dev\\Documents\\jira\\work\\ABC04214017-long-path-qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm\\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm2\\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm3\\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm-qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm4\\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm5\\qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcv\\qwertypoiuyalskdjfhg\\ABC04214017_03.raw_fhhzcqaj_wLM(4)\\objs\\RemPartic.fast",
            "-H",
            "100000"
    };

    Process process = runtime.exec(cmd);
    InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Hope this helps.